# ElectronJS - How can I have a consistent navbar across all my electron pages?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I am building an `Electron` application using `Twitter Bootstrap`. I managed to integrate `Bootstrap` in the application and load the main page.

My question is, how can I have a consistent `navbar`? instead of having to reload it every time because reusing the same code in every single page doesn't seem to be the right way.

Is there a better practice? or any advice?

Comment: An `iframe` for your page content would be a place to start, you can add a `name` attribute to it and let the links in the navbar refer to it by using `target="name"`.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks, I have one last question, what is your opinion of those javascripts frameworks like angular and vue, is it advisable to use them? in your opinion

Comment: I never used them because I feel at home at C-Alike languages and only use Electron as some "hobby" tool, but from what I've heard, they should be worth learning, so why not give them a try?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner so normally when you use electron, you use normal javscript, html, and css. right? and thanks for the help

Comment: Right. You're welcome.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner one last question, and am sorry to disturb you this much. Is it complex to connect between the front-end and the back-end (NodeJS and MongoDB) using the normal javascript and html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150077/discussion-between-alexander-leithner-and-mazin).